# Populate Auto Increment

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Say I have a table structure like this:

```
create table #Test (name varchar(100))
insert into #Test (name) values ('Ian')
insert into #Test (name) values ('Dave')
insert into #Test (name) values ('Simon')
insert into #Test (name) values ('Tim')
insert into #Test (name) values ('Andy')
insert into #Test (name) values ('Sarah')
```

How do I get a result set like this:

```
1 Ian
2 Dave
3 Simon
4 Tim
5 Andy
6 Sarah
```

I have tried using row number() and dense rank() but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: `ID identity(1,1)` doesn't create  numbers? `SELECT ID, name FROM #temp`

Comment: @lad2025, it was a typo.  I have modified the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `row_number() over (order by (select null))` might work, but I don't think the order is guaranteed to be in the order of insertion - data returned from select statements represent unordered sets if not explicitly ordered.

The best solution would be to add an identity column or a timestamp at insertion.

```
select * , r = row_number() over (order by (select null)) from #Test
```

or perhaps you could alter the table to add an identity column like so:

```
alter table #test add id int identity(1,1)
```